# How to merge PDF generated with react-pdf with an existing PDF? (JS/node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-pdf

My task: I generate a PDF with react-pdf based on data in my app. Then I want to merge this generated PDF with an already existing PDF.

My problem: With react-pdf I can get access to the document's blob data, but as far as I understand, this file is not saved anywhere. However, all JS tools for merging PDFs I found, enable you to merge PDFs only if you pass paths to files.

Can you see any solutions to this problem?
My idea was to save this generated PDF server-side, transform it somehow to PDF from BLOB, use some merging tool and then bring back the final merged PDF to client-side, but it seems quite (too?) complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here it my code for the same situation as you:

```
<Button
        className={classes.download}
        onClick={
            async () => {
                const doc = <InvoicePDF number={number} date={date} totalHours={totalHours} formattedHours={formattedHours} />
                const asPdf = pdf()

                asPdf.updateContainer(doc)

                let initialBlob = new Blob([fileRef.current.files[0]], { type: 'application/pdf' })
                let appendixBlob = await asPdf.toBlob()

                let merger = new PDFMerger()
                await Promise.all([initialBlob, appendixBlob].map(async (file) => await merger.add(file, null)))

                const mergedPdf = await merger.saveAsBlob()
                // merger = null
                // initialBlob = null
                // appendixBlob = null

                saveAs(mergedPdf, `Appendix${number}.pdf`)
            }}
    >
        Download
    </Button>
```

Where `InvoicePDF` is created with `react-pdf/renderer` and with [pdf-merger-js](https://github.com/nbesli/pdf-merger-js) I merge them.

It works, it does what it needs, but sometimes it does not merge them in the order I need.

Comment: Regarding your "order problem": I think the fact that you map over the blobs creates a race condition. The mapping function executes each arrow function right away so the one that finishes first creates the first pdf/page. This specific case is one of the few where I would use a "for-loop", since it is the only way to enforce an order. The `Promise.all()` call only waits for all promises to be resolved.

Comment: I have typescript and this line is causing some issues: 
 await merger.add(file, null)

Specifically: Argument of type 'Blob' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Buffer | ArrayBuffer'.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Fixed it by converting all the blobs to arrayBuffers using blob.arrayBuffer()